# TypeScript 'cannot find module...' in Vue project

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, import, vuejs2

I'm using TypeScript in Vue project.

But when I try to import vue file, I can't get .vue file since the 'cannot find module...' error.

[image]

What is weird is that intellisense only shows the directory right upper the .vue file.

[image: Intellisense shows the directory well]
Intellisense shows the directory well

[image: But it doesn't show the .vue file inside it]
But it doesn't show the .vue file inside it

I also have vue-shim.d.ts file in root directory.

Comment: Have you found a solution for it? I have the same issue

Comment: @RobinSchambach No I didn't... I'm using React now so I'm not facing that issue but didn't solve that.

Answer (score 11):

Try adding the following into **index.d.ts** in the project root, works for now.

```
declare module '*.vue' {
    import Vue from 'vue'
    export default Vue
}
```

or try to configure the path in tsconfig with

```
"paths": { "@/*":["./src/*"] }
```

or edit includes in tsconfig with

```
"include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.vue"]
```

Answer (score 11):

You should install [TypeScript Vue Plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vue.vscode-typescript-vue-plugin) and [Vue Language Features](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vue.volar).

Comment: Don't forget to disable the built-in TypeScript support in VS Code. https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/overview.html#volar-takeover-mode

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Vue 3 you should add this into a type file like `vue.d.ts`:

```js
declare module '*.vue' {
  import type {DefineComponent} from 'vue'
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  const component: DefineComponent<object, object, any>
  export default component
}
```

You can see it working here: [source](https://github.com/mutoe/vue3-realworld-example-app/blob/master/src/env.d.ts)

Answer (score 2):

In my case the issue is with **VS Code**. After doing

```
Shift + CMD + P  -> Restart typescript server (Mac)
```

The lint issue is no more.

Comment: Is there any way to not having to do this again and again each time it brokes?

Answer (score 0):

For me, following resolved the issue `Windows 10`:

1. Focus on any *.ts (preferably for which you are getting error)

   ```
   CTRL + SHIFT + P -> Restart TS Server
   ```
2. Focus on any *.vue (preferably in which you are getting error)

   ```
   CTRL + SHIFT + P -> Restart Volar server
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I was working on IntelliJ 2023.2.2 and I had the same issue. None of the other solution worked, until I selected "Repair IDE"

[image]

Comment: I was trying all the work arounds on vs-code. (Having installed the vue extensions and all.) Closing the editor and opening the project back up fixed the issue.